# SQL - Get previous row and duplicate it with a condition

Tags: mysql

I have a table like below

```
ID      status          message     set  
---------------------------------------
1       Completed       step1       1  
2       Completed       step2       1  
3       Failed          step3       1  
4       Completed       step1       2  
5       Completed       step2       2  
6       Failed          step3       2
```

For each set,   if there is a failed step, I need to duplicate the previous step and create a new row with status as "New".
So my table needs to look like

```
ID      status          message     set  
---------------------------------------
1       Completed       step1       1  
2       Completed       step2       1  
3       Failed          step3       1  
4       Completed       step1       2  
5       Completed       step2       2  
6       Failed          step3       2  
7       New             step2       1  
8       New             step2       2
```

Can someone help me with an SQL query here?
I have been trying to write something with Lag and db_cursor, but no luck so far. I will be keep on trying and if someone points me into right direction, it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks Giorgos for the editing! I was struggling on how to do it

Comment: What if step 1 fails?

Comment: If one of the steps fails.. does it continue to the next one ?

Comment: please consider that step 1 and step 2 never fails

Comment: Are there always exactly 3 steps?

Comment: I really think you need to define 'previous' - unless you're sure that you're really only saying `INSERT step2 WHERE step3 = 'failed'` (pseudo-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I arrived at the below solution.

```
DECLARE @set INT,
        @id  INT

--create a temporary table collecting the set value for the rows with failed message

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#failList') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #failList
SELECT  set
INTO    #failList
FROM    my_table WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE  status = 'Failed'
and message = 'step3'

--loop over the failList and match the step to get the previous row and duplicate it

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM #failList)
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @step = step
FROM    #failList

INSERT  INTO my_table (status, message, set)
SELECT  'New', message, set]
FROM    my_table d WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE   d.set = @set
    and message = 'step2'

DELETE FROM #failList WHERE set = @set      
END
```